# How to replace all values in my dataframe containing the string "x" with NAs?

Tags: r, csv

Solved

I cached some excel files into csv's, problem is in the excel sheets rather than giving blank values where none exists, there is inputted "x" or "xx" up to "xxxxx" and I need to convert all of those into NA's. What should I do? Some of the more complicated functions that I find in solutions online in R don't make sense to me (like apply + function + grepl) but I can understand things like grepl individually however cannot seem to find something that works.

I have tried

```
df <- replace(df, df == grepl(df, "x"), NA) %>%
write_csv("df.csv")
```

However I get an

> error: my df (pattern in grepl) has length >1

and only the first element will be used (I'm assuming the first column).

I've also done things individually by column, but I'm looking for something that scales.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and try to give an example so that it is easy for others to help you.

Comment: you should have `grepl("x",df)` instead

Comment: Unfortunately switching it did not work :(

Comment: `replace(df,structure(grepl("x",unlist(df),.Dim=dim(df)),NA)`

Answer (score 0):

```
df[sapply(df, grepl, pattern = 'x')] <- NA
```